# Добавить кнопку при клике открывается новая страница с формой для заполнения и отправкой данных в базу

Tags: php

Добрый день подскажите как именно реализовать данную задачу?
Добавить кнопку Просмотр
При клике по кнопке открывается отдельная страница в кабинете со следующими данными 1) Заголовок - Данные для сертификата курса *название курса*, 2) Имя: name 3) Фамилия: sername 4) Отчество: middle_name
Возле каждого из 3х полей стоит карандашик и фраза Изменить
Если хотябы по одному полю было внесено изменение , под контактными данными появляется кнопка - Сохранить
При клиеке по кнопке сохранить - данные отправляются в revelation (кнопка исчезает)
в формировании хмл используются следующие поля - client_name="NAME"      client_middle_name=""
      client_last_name=""  , курс айди

Comment: А теперь конкретно - с чем именно из всего перечисленного возникли затруднения?

Answer (score 1):

силами php это не реализуется.
Но вы можете вынести свою форму и ее обработку на php в другой файл например form.php и затем сделать ссылку или кнопку которая перейдет на вашу форму.
Варианты которые вам помогут :
1. Сделать кнопку в виде ссылки с помощью тега 'a' и атрибута target='_blank'
и застилизовать тег под кнопку 
2. Сделать это на js onclick='window.open('form.php')'
3. Можно еще скрыть форму на странице через display:none и затем открыть ее по клику на кнопку  display:block;
4. Можно получить форму через ajax и вставить на страницу по нажатию на кнопку
5. Можно взять React и запилить вашу форму на SPA

Comment: может есть пример как такая задача уже реализована?

Answer (score 0):

AJAX. На одной и той же странице (если я правильно понял задание ) рисуешь что тебе нужно, и твою форму, которой делаешь display:none. При клике на кнопку display:block. 
Js валидируешь ввод (прим: jQuery ==> on('change',.....)), если поменялось что-то, кнопку тоже в блок, и вуаля